# If $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$, are compact subspaces of $[0,1]$ then $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology

> **Proposition B:** The countably infinite product of closed sets is closed.

> **Theorem A:** The Hilbert cube $I^{\infty}$ is compact.

> **Question:** If $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$, are compact subspaces of $[0,1]$, deduce from **Theorem A** and **Proposition B**, that $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$ is compact.

I don't know if this argument is right: As each $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$, are compact subspaces of the Hausdorff space $[0,1]$, each $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)$ is closed. By **Proposition B**, it follows $X:=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)\subseteq\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}[0,1]=I^{\infty}$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert cube. By **Theorem A**, the Hilbert cube is compact, so $X$ is a closed subspace of a compact space, hence compact.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can reach the same conclusion using Tychonoff's theorem

Comment: @Alessandro: Thanks for the confirmation! I know of Tychonoff's Theorem, but at this point in my text it hasn't been proven for infinite (or general) products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is completely correct. It's the idiosyncratic order of theorems in Topology without Tears that provides this circumspect way of proving this fact.

Comment: Hi Henno, I'm interested to know how you knew it was Topology without Tears based off the question...have you read (or skimmed) the text before? If so, what's your thoughts on it? I'm using it as a refresher before an algebraic topology course.

Comment: @D.Math I recognise the style (also in notation).